# How to reference a numbered cell

Tags: front-end, hyperlink

I want to have a numbered celltype, say '1.7.2 exercise' which counts up, when I put in a new cell of this type ('exercise').
Later in the notebook (or even in a different notebook in the same folder), I want to have another cell with a different titel but the same number as the former cell.

So the cell should read, for example, '1.7.2 solution'.

How should I set up the counters and tags?

Comment: You can do this kind of thing with hyperlinks. A good place to start is with [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpHyperlinks.html). I would like to more specific, but your question isn't clear. Which cell is referenced by "1.7.2 exercise" and which by "1.7.2 solution". Are these meant to be cell tags? Or are they cell style with a counter? Or something else? Don't answer in a comment. Edit your question, making it clearer.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate answer. I edited my former question.

Comment: What if the exercise number changes while solution notebook is closed. Then you close exercise and open solution notebook. How could it know about that change. Working around all those edge cases is not worth the effort imo.

Comment: Thank you, you are definitly right. I keep the exercises and solutions in one notebook, the solutions at the end.  It works with Tags an hyperlinks.